# php paypal is not return anything

Tags: php, paypal

I'm test my site with paypal to see if i am receiving money and my system is being updated

When I ask to send email with all the information in POST I get empty email. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
$req .= payment_safe_check ($_POST);

$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$mode = strtolower($paymod_data['PAYMENT_MODE']);

    mail("to email", "subject",serialize($_POST) );


if ($mode == 'test')
{
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
}
else
{
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
}

if (!$fp)
{
    // HTTP ERROR
    die ("Error");
}
else 
{
    // NO HTTP ERROR
    fputs ( $fp, $header . $req );
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
        {
            processing ( $_POST );
        }
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
        {

        }
    }
    fclose ($fp);
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that sends the email?

Comment: I removed it. it was after $mode.

Comment: I have added the mail to my code same place where it was. When I receive email its completely blank.

Comment: Are you sure $_POST contains variables?  Can you do a var_dump on it before the mail() line to make sure?

Comment: Thats what I have done. to post all veriables to mail in text format.

Comment: I see that you are using `mail("to email", "subject",serialize($_POST) );` but I want to see whether or not $_POST contains any data.  If it does, try putting the variables into a string and then sending a string, instead of using the serialize method.

Comment: I'm getting the values but none of them are if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
Please help me.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: paypal is return strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") as 1 rather then 0, has they change they code.

Comment: That I don't know.  I doubt they would change something like this, though.

Comment: When I ask the api to send me email with all the data mail("to email", "subject",serialize($_POST) ); i get everything but when I put the email in                  if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)   nothing is received i wont to know why i wont begetting any information everything seem to be ok.

Comment: Go ahead and do a `var_dump($res)` to see what you're comparing "VERIFIED" to.

Comment: nothing was returned when eneter this code var_dump($res)

Comment: Assuming you put it in the right place, that means you're not getting any response or you're not collecting the correct variable from paypal.

Comment: i put the mail code in while loop with  var_dump($res)  in body text.

Comment: Put `var_dump($res)` in the while code since that is context in which the variable exists.

Comment: after putting serialize($res). i'm keep getting... . .s:26:"HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request, s:20:"Content-Length: 19, s:2:", s:19:"Connection: close, s:15:"Server: BigIP, s:19:"Invalid Host header";

Comment: Well this solves the problem of paypal not returning anything.  I now suggest you open a new question with your new error.  Thanks, glad to help.

Comment: I have create new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429750/paypal-ipn-not-return-verified-to-0

Answer (score 0):

Put var_dump($res) in the while code since that is context in which the variable exists.

Comment: I have put it inside while loop

Comment: Good, so now we just need to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: I have create new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429750/paypal-ipn-not-return-verified-to-0