# PayPal IPN not return VERIFIED to 0

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have asked my paypal api to send email of $res to see what the response is. Inside of the while (!feof($fp)) {}

This is what i'm getting from $res to my email

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: BigIP
Connection: close
Content-Length: 19
Invalid Host header
```

This is my paypal code.

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
$req .= payment_safe_check ($_POST);

$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$mode = strtolower($paymod_data['PAYMENT_MODE']);

    mail("to email", "subject",serialize($_POST) );


if ($mode == 'test')
{
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
}
else
{
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
}

if (!$fp)
{
    // HTTP ERROR
    die ("Error");
}
else 
{
    // NO HTTP ERROR
    fputs ( $fp, $header . $req );
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
        {
            processing ( $_POST );
        }
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
        {

        }
    }
    fclose ($fp);
}
```

This doesn't work `if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0){}` but if I change it to `if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == -1){}` It works fine.

**UPDATE**

I have change my code to

```
$mode = $paymod_data['PAYMENT_MODE'];
$paypal_url = ($mode == 'test') ? 'www.sandbox.paypal.com' : 'www.paypal.com';

$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval)
{
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
$req .= payment_safe_check ($_REQUEST);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$paypal_url.'/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: '.$paypal_url));

$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    processing ( $_POST );
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
```

Can someone please confirm if they is any problem with this code.

Answer (score 1):

VERIFIED and INVALID are the two responses that you need to validate once you get the response back from PAYPAL. 
 You can refer the code samples at 
 https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623

Answer (score 0):

strcmp check to see if one string is "larger" than the other.  Is is case sensitive and can be thrown off by spaces and line feeds.

I would recommend you instead use

```
if ( stristr($res,"VERIFIED") === 0 )   {}
else if ( stristr($res,"INVALID") === 0 )   {}
```

Comment: after changing my code i got this. HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: BigIP
Connection: close
Content-Length: 19

Invalid Host header

Comment: Do you know whats the new paypal IPN code I can use. is this the latest code https://www.x.com/instant-payment-notification-4

Answer (score 0):

the problem in the url could not be found ...
you have to change the url to be like the following ...

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');   // (for Sandbox IPNs)
$ch = curl_init(' https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');   // (for live IPNs)
```